# Output ffmpeg Filter Details to Log File

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm likely just missing this, but ... is there a way to tell ffmpeg to also output information about the used filters / filter chain to the log file?

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear what you mean. If you want some of the higher-level logs produced by filters, increase loglevel to verbose or debug e.g. `-loglevel debug`.

Comment: This works, see the info there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way is to run with the `-report` option, which produces a file called `ffmpeg-<date>-<time>.log`, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg started on 2019-04-18 at 11:34:01
Report written to "ffmpeg-20190418-113401.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -report -i test.mp4 -t 1 -filter:v "scale=-2:240" out.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  ...
```

You'll get a copy of the command line used, from which you can extract the filters.

You can also run with `-loglevel debug` which prints the filter graph configuration, e.g.:

```
Applying option filter:v (set stream filtergraph) with argument scale=-2:240.
```

The filters also report their detailed options:

```
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7f9a54405300] Setting 'w' to value '-2'
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7f9a54405300] Setting 'h' to value '240'
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7f9a54405300] Setting 'flags' to value 'bicubic'
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7f9a54405300] w:-2 h:240 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
```

This can be parsed, although it'll not be that robust in case the log format changes. You'd have to extract the values from the "Setting x to y" strings.

Comment: Yes, loglevel works, not sure if I see report working though. Thanks!

Comment: The report should be written to the current working directory. If not, check that the user has write permissions.